# Terraform .12 is it possible to add tags to an Existing RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

We are using RDS in PROD and planning to add few tags to start/stop programmatically the RDS instance. Is it possible to add tags to existing RDS using terraform? by any means data resource or a hack by null resource in case straight forward way is not available in Terraform. I don't want to use BOTO or CLI commands for describing the tags as most of my provisioning code is in terraform.

Comment: You can import existing rds into terraform's control. Then you could updated the tags.

Comment: @Marcin, Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate with some sudo code?

Comment: check out examples at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#import